# jQuery Hide/Show only on the parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I'm new to jQuery and am experimenting on hiding and showing `li` lists.

I have it working to where the when you click on the parent li (`li.2015`) the sub li (`ul.2015`) list is shown and hidden.

However, I only want this behavior to work on the parent li (`li.2015`) and not when clicking on the sub li list (`ul.2015`).

Right now it hides when I click on the sub li list (`ul.2015`) which I don't want to happen, I only want the show/hide to function on the parent li (`li.2015`).

**What changes do I need to make to my jQuery for this?**

html

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="date">
        <li class="2015">2015
        <ul class="2015">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
(function () {
    var ulSub = $('ul.2015');
    $('li.2015').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        ulSub.toggle();
    });
    ulSub.hide();
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        ulSub.hide();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub item hides because you wrap `ul` with `li.2015`.

Your html

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="date">
        <li class="2015">2015
        <ul class="2015">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When you click on subitem then first will go through parent `li` which you wrapped your child with.

Try like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="date">
        <li class="2015">2015</li>

            <ul class="2015">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>


    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var ulSub = $('ul.2015');
ulSub.hide();
$('li.2015').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ulSub.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only following code and remove other code from jquery code.

```
var ulSub = $('ul.2015');

$('li.2015').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ulSub.toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o7qaa2cp/)

Comment: Tried this, clicking the `ulSub li` list (1,2,3) still hides it. I only want this to work on the parent li.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Parent li contains the child li elements that is the reason it is happening in that way.
try below code using extra span element will solve the problem.

```
    <div class="content">
    <ul class="date">
        <li class="2015"><span id="spanId">2015</span>
        <ul class="2015">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    (function() {
var ulSub = $('ul.2015');

$('li.2015 span#spanId').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ulSub.toggle();
});

    $('a[href="#"').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

})();
```